# SSH key required for every connection

Tags: ssh, sshd, ssh-keygen

I installed an ssh key on my machine to connect to a server, why does it ask me to insert the password for that key even if I am trying to connect to a different server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are the key files named ?

If the name of the key you installed is `id_rsa` / `id_rsa.pub` etc then `ssh` will always attempt to use it for a connection if the server has `PubkeyAuthentication yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

If you rename the files from their default names when you are connecting to that one server you will have to use `ssh -i /path/to/key`, otherwise every time you use `ssh` it will try to use those keys if they are using any of the default key names.

From `man ssh`

```
-i identity_file
             Selects a file from which the identity (private key) for public
             key authentication is read.  The default is ~/.ssh/identity for
             protocol version 1, and ~/.ssh/id_dsa, ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa,
             ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 and ~/.ssh/id_rsa for protocol version 2.
             Identity files may also be specified on a per-host basis in the
             configuration file.  It is possible to have multiple -i options
             (and multiple identities specified in configuration files).  If
             no certificates have been explicitly specified by the
             CertificateFile directive, ssh will also try to load certificate
             information from the filename obtained by appending -cert.pub to
             identity filenames.
```